# Merge Annotated images into one dataset (In the same project)

Tags: roboflow

Roboflow is a great platform for computer vision labeling. There is a problem I am encountering tho. I am uploading the data on multiple times and doing iterations of labeling. I ended by having these datasets inside one project. Now I want to use annotated images from some of them. The problem is I am not able to use any annotated images but the first uploaded and annotated images only. Can you please tell me if there is a way to do so?

[Multiple DataSets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLrzd.png)

Answer (score 0):

did you click “Add to Dataset” after completing labeling on all of the images? You’ll need to do that so they’re all in the dataset.

Next, generate a *new* version of the dataset. Datasets generated on Roboflow are “point in time” versions.

Let me know if this doesn’t help, and I’m happy to look into it more.

https://docs.roboflow.com/exporting-data

https://help.roboflow.com/en_US/get-started/workspaces-projects-and-versions

You can also begin with separate projects if you would like “isolated” projects before merging them together.
https://help.roboflow.com/en_US/guides/merging-projects-or-datasets

Comment: Thanks for replying,
I can't find where the "Add to Dataset" button